# Blank Screen in running flutter app in release mode

Tags: flutter

Pretty much this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36247 .
Looking for any support here.

PLEASE NOTE ISSUE WITH IOS ONLY.

The app works perfectly in the simulator and also when connected via USB. 
But when I build the app for release and distribute through testflight. It is showing blank screen.

I have a simple log to create on my home page which never gets triggered. So it must be before that the app is getting terminated or something.

The app shows no crashes( running crashlytics)

Looking for some help.

Comment: sometimes it happens because of an exception you ignored but sometimes it happens because you didn't install cocoapods or android toolchain

Comment: Please run your application in debug mode in iOS device and check there any exception arise? This issue should be with any package which is not working as expected in iOS.

Comment: from xcode have you write the signing profile ? please add the signing profile .your problem will be solved

Comment: did you added internet permission in  info.plist

Answer (score 1):

This is because **Incorrect use on parent widget**.
You can see it in console while simulator running.

This happens when use Expanded without row/column or positioned without stack and so on.
It is also happen in android too.

Comment: yes, this is right. I have faced the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Run your app on profile mode then test the whole app manually.
**or**
In the debug mode when you run your app, open the terminal, and then start testing your app hopefully you will get an issue Like
**Incorrect Use of Parent Widget**
Mostly this issue was caused by Expanded widgets when we used them in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to your plugins not working properly at runtime.

Check your Flutter log to see if there are any errors occurring during debug mode.

The app will show a blank screen if there are still errors present in your app.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me also when I was releasing one of my Flutter iOS apps on Appstore and Apple Distribution Review team rejected my build several times. I was ignoring the exception of my child views overflowing to screen which causing a Blank Screen on iOS on release mode. I fix it by aligning my views properly and adjusting according to the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your app in debug mode and when something goes wrong, you see the scary red error screen with logs. In release mode, you just see a grey screen.

Now, when you run your app in debug mode, at times there are some errors that are thrown but we mistakenly ignore them as we see the app is running perfectly on screen but if you open your logs in debug mode, you will see some error messages.

solution 1:
Run your app in debug mode and check logs, I am sure you will find the problem there.

solution 2:
try to add the Internet permission
in `android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml`
add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

solution 3:
Review your UI Code Responsivity

Comment: Bro has stated that its an ios only issue.

Comment: Hi @DevonRay if it's an iOS issue, so you can escape the second solution

Answer (score -2):

you can try
1.flutter clean
2.flutter pub get
**3.flutter build ios**
then archive and try again with testflight or production